# Levi-Civita and Einstein summation notation question

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, tensors

My question is probably simple but how do you calculate:
$\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon^{ijk}$

I know the sum it represent's but how do you calculate it?

Comment: Some tips: Which summands are nonzero? What are the values they can take? When do they take those values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Einsteins's summation convention (unless I remembered incorrectly the definition of Levi-Civita symbols...):

$$
\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon^{ijk}=\sum_{i,j,k=1}^{3}\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon^{ijk}=\sum_{i,j,k=1}^{3}\varepsilon_{ijk}^{2}
$$

Since $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ can be $0$, $-1$ or $1$, its square is either $0$ or 1. Also, $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ is zero iff any of the indices is repeated. So there are as many $1$'s in the summation as permutations of $\{i,j,k \}$, that is, $6$.

So $\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon^{ijk}=6$.

Hope this helps!